# How can I change the prompt of the terminal permanently

Tags: command-line, prompt, ps1

How can I change prompt name seen at terminal?

my prompt :

```
<user_name>@<user_name>-MEGA-BOOK-VR320:~$
```

It is too long. I want to change it to:

```
gcc :
```

However, I should see the path when I go from one directory to another.

```
gcc :~$ cd X_directory
gcc :~/X_directory$
```

How can I do that, permanently?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Test it with this:

```
export PS1="gcc :\w\$ "
```

If if its what you want, then change it in your `.bashrc` file:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

delete or comment out this line:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

and replace with

```
PS1='gcc :\w\$ '
```

- *note* if your username is "gcc" then you could replace `gcc` with `\u`

Hope that helps. More info on PS1 [here](http://jamiedubs.com/ps1-collection-customize-your-bash-prompt).