# How to change the text after username@ in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, username

I just installed Ubuntu and opened an admin panel where I saw that I accidentally allowed the system to use my laptop's name. Can anyone suggest how would I remove it?

[image: this is the one I want to change]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the 'hostname'. Check this question for how to change it: [How do I change the hostname without a restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart)

If you want to have a completely different prompt, not in the form of user@hostname, check out the answer here: [change prompt of terminal, permanently | how](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152911/change-prompt-of-terminal-permanently-how)

Comment: Happy to help. If you could mark my answer as correct, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

That's actually the standard Ubuntu Bash prompt which shows your hostname, you can change your hostname if what bothers you is that it's so long otherwise you can just remove it.

Start by reading what your prompt is actually set to look like using `echo ${PS1}`. You should get a rather unreadable string that contains `@\h` at some point. Removing that part will remove the hostname from the prompt.
Simply export your new settings with `export PS1="your_new_string"`.

If you want to make that change persistent, add it to your `.bashrc`.