# How to reduce initials of the console prompt

Tags: command-line, kubuntu

I don't know the term of the initial text before the command prompt of the console or the terminal, but the screen shot below should demonstrate well what I mean:

[image]

I want to reduce the highlighted text in the image: `said@said-Satellite-L850-A700:` to something like: `said@pc` or even to be only `$` without any modification for the computer's name. Does it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the prompt of the terminal permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152911/how-can-i-change-the-prompt-of-the-terminal-permanently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the prompt in Bash (and Zsh) by setting the `PS1` environment variable.

You may do this in your `$HOME/.bashrc` file, for example.

Example:

```sh
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

or for `your-user@pc` use

```sh
PS1='\u@pc'
```

or go simple

```sh
PS1='$ '
```

Here's some of the magic tokens you can use.

```
\h : the hostname up to the first ‘.’
\H : the hostname
\u : your username
\t : time in 24hr format
\w : current working dir
```

You can apply colour codes too, should you wish.

### EDIT: colour, bold etc.

ANSI escape sequences can be specified like `\033[` then some numbers for bold and colours joined with `;` then `m` and can be reset with `\033[0m;`

e.g. `PS1='\033[31mxxx\033[0m '` would give you a red `xxx` as a prompt.

Very mini cheatsheet, replace `31` (Red) in the above with..

- `1;31` for bold red
- `1` for bold default colour
- `31;43` for red text (31) on yellow background (43). The second, background colour uses the same code as the foreground but +10
- `38;2;r;g;b` where you replace `r` `g` and `b` with a value 0-255 for red green blue, e.g. `38;2;255;180;0` would set it to a nice orange

`PS1='\033[31mxxx\033[0m '` would give you a red `xxx` as a prompt.

Please see [an excellent answer at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33206814/623519) for a fuller list.

Comment: Could you please tell how to use color codes and if it is possible to make it in bold?

Comment: @SaidbakR there you go